# Need to replace water shut off valve in house but city can't find water main shut off in the yard

Tags: water, valve, shutoff

The city water main shut off is in the front yard of our 1960s home that we've lived in for 15 years. A few decades ago, the previous owners filled in that part of the yard with a lot of fill to level it out – we were not made aware of this until a neighbor recently told us. Now our inside turn off valve is leaking and needs to be replaced - it's just a pipe coming up from the basement cement floor with a simple knob. The city can’t locate the main shut-off in the yard probably because it’s too deep for their metal detectors and they have no map of where it should be located.  To start digging could cost us thousands.  I’m wondering if title insurance should be covering this? Anyhow, is there some way to install a new shut off valve in the house without shutting off the city water line coming in?

Comment: I doubt title insurance would do anything for this. A homeowners warranty might, but they usually don't last that long.

Comment: One method I've seen used by a plumber is to take a long metal spike with a handle and stab down into the soil trying to hit the pipe, and trace it that way.  You know where one end of it is, where it exits your basement, so starting from the same position outside your house, you should be able to find where it goes as it heads towards the street.  I imagine this will only work with soil that is fairly wet.

Comment: how do they read your water meter?  Isn't there a shutoff at the meter?

Comment: Is it a metallic line?  If so, an underground cable/pipe locator should be able to find it regardless of how deep it is.  Call 811 and tell them you need locates in that area.  No charge!

Comment: The valve (and leak) are before the water meter in the basement - there is not a separate shut-off at meter. Yes 811 could possibly locate, but it could be 6, 8, 12 or more feet down and there are huge oak trees near by.  We'd have to get a back hoe and city involved thus costing $$$$.

Comment: So... you are not asking for help with method to find existing main control valve. You are looking for methods to change a valve **without** shutting off the water. If you revise the title of your post to clearly indicate what you really want, you may get more responses...

Comment: How does the valve leak -- water goes through it when you want the valve closed, or water leaks out into the room? In case of the former, don't worry about replacing the valve. Install a new valve downstream of it instead.

Comment: @freshop  What meter? I certainly don't have/need a water meter.

Answer (score 2):

### Freeze the pipe

I've heard tales of stopping a pipe for valve replacement by freezing the water but I haven't ever attempted it. Take this as an entirely untested theory. I suppose it might go something like the following.

Choose a location on the pipe sufficiently far from the valve to be replaced and pack dry ice around the pipe. It's probably a good idea to freeze a section several inches long at minimum. Have sufficient quantity of dry ice on hand to maintain the frozen section for longer than it takes to bring more dry ice, just in case things go horribly wrong and you need to maintain it frozen longer than expected.

Procedure could vary depending on whether the new valve can thread on to an existing adapter or pipe end or whether it's necessary to solder something (in the case of a copper tube service line).

There are plenty of risks involved, mostly distilling to "what happens if we get the old valve off but water gushes through before the new valve is in place?" I can't give advice on that, but I could suggest that you test the technique first. Freeze the pipe, but instead of proceeding with the valve replacement, open a faucet and wait to see how much working time the freeze provided.

### Other Alternatives

The one-call 811 service won't mark private facilities but they should mark at least the city-owned pipe coming from the street. Unfortunately the markings would be made by the utility owner (or their contractor)... so if the city water department already can't find your pipe, 811 may be no help. At that age your service line is almost certainly metallic so a locator worth their salt should be able to connect a transmitter to the line and locate it. Private underground locators also exist but I can't speak to their cost. In any case, merely having the line marked doesn't tell you where along the line the valve might be buried.

The city will have shutoff valves in their mains. They're frequently found at intersections. You may be able to negotiate with the city for a half-hour shut down of the section your house is connected to.

Finally.. (bear with me here) maybe it's time for an upgrade/replacement of the service line. It could be made of lead pipe, it could have corrosion built up inside it, who knows. It might be cost effective to have a new pipe installed with trenchless boring techniques. You get the new line into the house and plumbed to a valve, then let it be the city's problem to locate where your existing line connects with theirs and make the change. After the switch-over is done on their side you can freely disconnect the house plumbing from the old leaky valve and connect it to the shiny new valve and supply line.

Comment: Normally a line freeze is done with liquid nitrogen and some special equipment, and yes it works well as long as there is no flow through the pipe whilst the freeze is attempted.

Answer (score 1):

Get the utility back to use their metal detector.  Our detector can detect our curbstop boxes down past two feet.  If there is snow out then that may hinder the performance but otherwise they should find the curbstop.  It’s their box and valve.  Depending on your soil and the condition of the box and rod it may even be impossible to turn it off without fixing it first.

I’ve heard of people freezing; never seen it done.

The utility will not shut down the street(s) for your main valve.  There’s too much red tape (here if we did that all residences would be on a precautionary boil water advisory until two bacteriological samples came back clear which would take at least a week).

One option if the leak is getting really bad I’ve heard of being done here is remove the old valve live (not entirely sure how with the live line) and use a Sharkbite Valve (if available in your region).  Leave the Sharkbite open and then slide it on.  This is a temporary fix until the curbstop can be found and a soldered valve installed.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer, but did you mean "soldered valve" instead of "sautered valve"? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: I understand how to contribute.  I’ve been a member of Stack Overflow for a few years. :)  Also, Yes, I did mean soldered and have updated my answer with the correct spelling.

Comment: My water shut-off valve (my side, in my basement) was inoperable last year when I was doing a project.  I called a pro and he found the water utility's service valve in my meter hole (outside) was also inoperable.  I guess neither had been used in ages.  The utility came to assist.  I believe they temporarily shut off my street to replace the service valve.  It took them a couple days to get around to it since it was a non-emergency.

Comment: @Jeff Where I work our water lines are down 8’ all the way to the house so our water meter is in the house right after the main valve.  We do have a curbstop outside for disconnecting the supply if the house owner requires it or they don’t pay their bill.  The only thing that is our responsibility is the meter and its connection.  That’s the trouble with answering as each area has its own quirks and rules and procedures.

Comment: @DawsonIrvine - Maybe you just found an answer - stop paying the bill and wait for the water company to come and shut off the water!

Comment: "*I’ve heard of people freezing*"  I lost a toe that way.